# Removing URL's from Existing Entries

Tags: entries, structure, craft.entries

We've created a site which now has 40 entries in a Structure.  We need to retrospectively remove the URI's because there isn't an individual page for each entry, they're all on one page but search engines are tracking individual pages.

We've removed {slug} from the Section and replaced with 'projects' (no quotes) but of course CraftCMS sees this as duplicate when it tries to resave all the entries.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a quick but not elegant fix, You can disabled the entries you don't want to show up in the url.

When you want to use the content just put

```
 craft.entries({
   section: someSection,
   status: null
 })
```

or

```
 craft.entries({....}).status(null)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd first set up a 301 redirect to ensure that anyone who does land on one of these search engine indexed pages is redirected to the single page that lists them all.

Then I'd just turn URLs off for that Section.